# Hits on file age-de.xml on my website root

Tags: web, http-status-code-404

I have some hits on a file "age-de.xml" located on my website root (for instance : `http://example.org/age-de.xml`).

This file has never been present and is not linked anywhere.

Where does it comes from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is used for "youth protection", by [altersklassifizierung.de](https://www.altersklassifizierung.de/en)

Full specifications are available online : http://www.online-management-kontor.de/downloads/age-de-xml-label_definition_v3.0g_english1.pdf

Example file for labeling a whole domain and subdomain 12+ :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<age-declaration>
    <ageblock-basic>
        <age-issuer>www.example.org</age-issuer>
        <custom info="generator">label.usk.de</custom>
        <last-change>2012-11-05</last-change>
        <country>de</country>
        <label-version>1.0</label-version>
        <revisit-after>1days</revisit-after>
    </ageblock-basic>
    <ageblock-labeltype>
        <xmlfile>true</xmlfile>
        <httpheader>false</httpheader>
        <htmlmeta>false</htmlmeta>
        <label-z>false</label-z>
        <default-age>12</default-age>
    </ageblock-labeltype>
    <ageblock-labeltype-definition>
        <labeltype-xmlfile>
            <label class="default">
                <min-age>12</min-age>
                <default-age>12</default-age>
            </label>
            <label class="bewertungseinheit1">
                <age>12</age>
                <min-age>12</min-age>
                <default-age>12</default-age>
                <scope>*.example.org</scope>
            </label>
        </labeltype-xmlfile>
    </ageblock-labeltype-definition>
</age-declaration>
```

You can find online generators : http://www.usk.de/extramenue/login/publisher/weitere-leistungen/labelgenerator/